# Interface Projection DTO doesn't work with Spring Data R2DBC

Tags: java, spring-data-r2dbc

I tried to retrieve data with the custom query to Projection DTO:

DTO

```
public interface StudentTutorDto {

    String getStudentName();

    String getTutorName();

    String getStatus();

    String getPriority();

}
```

Repository

```
    @Query("""
            select
              s.name as studentName,
              t.name as tutorName,
              st.status as status,
              st.priority as priority
            from student s
            join student_tutor st on st.student_id = s.id
            join tutor t on t.id = st.tutor_id
            where s.id = :idStudent
            """
    )
    Mono<StudentTutorDto> get(Long idStudent);
```

When I try to call `StudentRepository#get` Repository tries to parse it to `StudentEntity`. How can I solve it to parse it to DTO which is mentioned as generinc in Mono?